# How to define different text processing logic to different inputs with CatBoostClassifier

Tags: python, catboost

I want to build a catboost classifier that uses several text inputs.
each of these needs different type of vectorization logic (some of them word level, some of them character ngrams)

the main documentation I'm trying to follow is here: https://catboost.ai/docs/features/text-features.html

I managed to define a custom "text pipeline" in common for all fields:

```
import catboost
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'a': ['Hello World', 'This is a test', 'foo', 'fooo'],
    'b': ['Hello World', 'This is a test', 'foo', 'fooo'],
    'y': [0,0,1,1]
})

text_processing_options ={
    "tokenizers" : [{
        "tokenizer_id" : "tok",
        "delimiter" : " ",
        "lowercasing" : "true"
    }],

    "dictionaries" : [{
        "dictionary_id" : "word_uni",
        "gram_order" : "1",
        "occurrence_lower_bound":"1"
    }, {
        "dictionary_id" : "char_ngram",
        "gram_order" : "3",
        "token_level_type": 'Letter',
        "occurrence_lower_bound": "1"
    }],

    "feature_processing" : {
        "a" : [{
            "tokenizers_names" : ["tok"],
            "dictionaries_names" : ["word_uni"],
            "feature_calcers" : ["BoW"]
        }],
        "b" : [{
            "tokenizers_names" : ["tok"],
            "dictionaries_names" : ["char_ngram"],
            "feature_calcers" : ["BoW"]
        }],
    }
}
model = catboost.CatBoostClassifier(text_processing=text_processing_options, iterations=10)
model.fit(df[['a','b']], df['y'], text_features=['a', 'b'])
```

but trying different logic for each column (based on my understanding of the API fails:

```
import catboost
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'a': ['Hello World', 'This is a test', 'foo', 'fooo'],
    'b': ['Hello World', 'This is a test', 'foo', 'fooo'],
    'y': [0,0,1,1]
})

text_processing_options ={
    "tokenizers" : [{
        "tokenizer_id" : "tok",
        "delimiter" : " ",
        "lowercasing" : "true"
    }],

    "dictionaries" : [{
        "dictionary_id" : "word_uni",
        "gram_order" : "1",
        "occurrence_lower_bound":"1"
    }, {
        "dictionary_id" : "char_ngram",
        "gram_order" : "3",
        "token_level_type": 'Letter',
        "occurrence_lower_bound": "1"
    }],

    "feature_processing" : {
        "a" : [{
            "tokenizers_names" : ["tok"],
            "dictionaries_names" : ["word_uni"],
            "feature_calcers" : ["BoW"]
        }],
        "b" : [{
            "tokenizers_names" : ["tok"],
            "dictionaries_names" : ["char_ngram"],
            "feature_calcers" : ["BoW"]
        }],
    }
}
model = catboost.CatBoostClassifier(text_processing=text_processing_options, iterations=10)
model.fit(df[['a','b']], df['y'], text_features=['a', 'b'])
```

another issue is wether it's possible to get \ log the processed inputs for troubleshooting?